# Facebook Login Integration Error:

Tags: facebook, redirect, oauth, facebook-login

I'm working with a contest platform and am trying to get it to where and individual can create an account via Facebook.

The biggest issue I'm running into is that whenever I enter the domains into the App Domains portion I receive this:"App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL, or Secure Page URL. Please correct these domains:"

Additionally, when I attempt to test the Facebook login button, I receive this error message in the pop-up:"URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs."

I've inquired with the Support Team from the contest platform and was informed of this:
"We had the Engineers look at this issue on your site and it looks like the configuration in facebook might not be correct.

What you need to make sure of is that facebook login authentication is enabled for the Website (Web) then only it will work.

The app domain:------
Contact email: your email address

Then in the Website section 
Site url:------"

I can't seem to locate where the "Site URL" section is that I need to be putting in a url. I've put in the OAuth Client Redirect URLs...maybe they aren't correct?

Need some major help here.

Comment: Add Website platform first

Comment: Perfect. I have that added. Any thought on what my OAuth redirect URI should look like after the -----.com/?

Comment: No you can use any URL you want